# Combining two tables in sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables in two separate sqlite3 databases.  The datatypes are identical, but the schemas slightly different. I want them to be a single table in a single database with the same schema as `Table 2`

#### Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE temp_entries (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    sensor NUMERIC, 
    temp NUMERIC, 
    date NUMERIC);
```

#### Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE "restInterface_temp_entry" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "dateTime" integer NOT NULL,
    "sensor" integer NOT NULL,
    "temp" integer NOT NULL
);
```

`id` is not unique between the two tables.  I would like to create another table with the same schema as `Table 2`.  I would like the `id` for the entries in Table 1 to start from 0 and then the entries from `table 2` to start after the last entry from `table 1`.

Ideally I would like to just add the entries from `Table 1` to `Table 2` and "reindex" the primary key so that it was in the same ascending order that "dateTime" is.

***UPDATE***: I now have both tables using the same schema, I did this by creating a new table with the same schema as `Table 2` into the database that held `Table 1`.  I than copied the data to the new table with something like:

```
INSERT INTO restInterface_temp_entry(id,dateTime,sensor,temp)
   ...> select id,date,sensor,temp FROM temp_entries;
```

#### Background

I used to record a bunch of `temp_entries` to a csv file.  I wanted to put the data into a format that was easier to work with and chose sqlite3.  I wrote a program that pulled all of the entries out and put them into `Table 1`.  I wasn't sure what I was doing at the time, and used `Table 2` for all new entries.  Now I want to combine them all, hopefully keeping id and date in ascending order.

Comment: So, what is your question? Why can't you write a programme in your favourite language to do just this?

Comment: I could do that, but I was hoping there was a way to merge to tables within sqlite3.  My question bois down to: How do you take data from one sqlite table and combine it with data from another, when the primary key isn't unique between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

- Open current database.
- Attach to original database

  ```
  ATTACH '/orig/db/location' as orig
  ```
- Move records from current database to old database, leaving out the PK

  ```
  insert into orig.restInterface_temp_entry(dateTime,sensor,temp)
  ...> select dateTime,sensor,temp from main.restInterface_temp_entry;
  ```
- Clear current databases table

  ```
  delete from main.restInterface_temp_entry where id > 0
  ```
- Copy everything updated records from original databases table back to current.

  ```
  insert into main.restInterface_temp_entry(id,dateTime,sensor,temp)
  ...> select id,dateTime,sensor,temp
  ...> from orig.restInterface_temp_entry;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming SQLLite supports INSERT INTO SELECT

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id, datetime, sensor, temp) 
    SELECT id, date, sensor, temp 
    FROM temp_entries
    ORDER BY id;
INSERT INTO newtable (id, datetime, sensor, temp) 
    SELECT "id", "dateTime", "sensor", "temp"
    FROM "restInterface_temp_entry"
    ORDER BY "id";
```

This should do the trick.