# Combining tables in SQLite3 without large data increases

Tags: database, sqlite

How can I combine three tables in a database, but not have a large increase in data storage needs at any point in the process?

I have inherited a database with three tables. Two have the same columns, and one drops one of the columns:

```
Table1:
    name
    info
    longkey
    shortkey

Table2:
    name
    info
    longkey
    shortkey

Table3:
    name
    info
    longkey
```

I want to create a single table with `name` and `info` columns and have no need for the remnants of other tables or the key fields. There are likely high numbers of duplicate entries between the three tables - an entry in table 1 will likely appear in table 2 and/or table 3.

The big problem, and the reason that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696155/combining-two-tables-in-sqlite3) is not suitable is that it leads to a large increase in size and I have limited space available.

What can I do, either in SQL or perhaps through Python Scripting or other methods, that will not lead to a large increase in data storage at any time during the process?

Comment: It is not possible to drop columns directly. You will need storage for the result, and again as much for temporary data while the query is running.

Comment: so it is not possible to run a procedural statement such as "for entry in table2, check if in table 1, add if not present, delete from table 2" and repeat for table 3?

Comment: You asked for a query. I would be possible to do everything manually (and you probably have to [disable transaction safety](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) to make it safe space and be efficient).

Comment: I have edited my question to open it up for any solution. Does this help?